# Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices and let $b$ and $c$ be column vectors. Then there exists a vecto....

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

> Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices and let $b$ and $c$ be vectors. Then there exists a vector $x$ with $Ax < b$ and $Bx ≤ c$, if and only if for all row vectors $y, z \ge 0$:
>
> (i) if $y^TA + z^TB = 0$ then $y^Tb + z^Tc \ge 0$; and
>
> (ii) if $y^TA + z^TB = 0$ and $y \neq 0$ then $y^Tb + z^Tc \gt 0$.

I saw this theorem in class, but without proof. In the textbook (Algorithms for Convex Optimization, Vishnoi) recommended it doesn't even appear. Can someone recommend a textbook that contains the demonstration?
Thanks for the attention.

Comment: are the components of b one by one larger than the components of a?

Comment: I don't know, you wrote $Ax<b$?

Comment: I just copied the theorem (which I did not understood)

Comment: You should do more yourself before posting, if I may say so. At least the notations should be clarified.

Comment: Do you know Farkas' Lemma? Because this is a result that can be derived from Farkas' Lemma, at least with $Ax \le b$. For $Ax < b$ you need to use some extra arguments.